# Font not being picked up in Swing Application when running in Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, fonts

I have developed a java swing application with a few JTextAreas and the font for the text area is set as follows:

```
    Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setFont(font);
```

The application was initially developed in Eclipse and not using Maven and the font in the text area was correctly rendered when the application was run within Eclipse and also when I created a runnable Jar fine and run from that.

As part of a migration to IntelliJ I created a Maven Project within Eclipse and moved my code into the Eclipse Maven project. I then found that and the font in the text area was NOT correctly rendered when the application was run within Eclipse but was when I created an runnable Jar file and run from that.

I then moved the code to a Maven Module within IntelliJ and hit the same issue. The font in the text area was NOT correctly rendered when the application was run within InteliJ but was when I created an runnable Jar file (via mvn install) and run from that.

I can only assume that I need to modify the POM in some way but am a total novice when it comes to Maven.

Suggestions?

Comment: Would using `Font.MONOSPACED` work for you? e.g., `Font font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12);`

Comment: That worked - but would still love to know why "Courier" doesn't.

Comment: I've no idea. Does your OS have a Courier font?

Comment: Yes - Windows, and the font specified is ONLY ignored if I am running the app within an IDE and within a Maven project.